# Is there any harm adding an element to a window's document that is not the one that it was created with?

Tags: javascript, dom

For instance, say I do this:

```
var otherWindow = window.open("otherfile.html", "_blank");
```

then some time later:

```
if(otherWindow.document && otherWindow.document.body) {
 var elem = document.createElement("DIV")
 elem.innerHTML = "hello here I am!";
 otherWindow.document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

This seems to work ok, but I am curious if there is any downside to the fact that elem was created with the first window's document, but appended to the second window's document.  Is this a big no-no?

Assume that I have my reasons for doing this, and that (since the element is actually created by library code) it would not be clean/trivial to create the element with "otherWindow.document".

Comment: @Mathletics: No, it's a method of the Document node itself, and the resultant element's `ownerDocument` property refers to the document.

Comment: Given that *window* is effectively an alias for the global object, and that some browsers implement prototype inheritance, creating a DOM element in one window and attaching it to a document in another window may create interdependencies between the windows. That may have an effect on memory and things like `if (element instanceof HTMLElement)`, since the instance's constructor may be from a different global context to the on in which the test is being performed and therefore return *false* when *true* might be expected.

Comment: @TimDown I notice that, in Chrome, ownerDocument will refer to the new document (the one the element was appended to).

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll be OK in at least some browsers but I think there may be exceptions and I don't know offhand what the DOM spec says about it. I would suggest trying it out in your target browsers.

There is also the DOM [`importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode) method that has pretty wide support and is designed for the task, so seems the safest option and the one I'd recommend.

Comment: I've never seen a problem, but seeing the importNode documentation was helpful. Seems that it works now, and when they changed it otherwise it broke lots of pages, but they still advise against such things.

Comment: One effect of using *importNode* is that the original node is cloned, so all listeners should be dropped (except perhaps in–line listeners). Also not sure this is relevant given that in the OP the created node is appended directly to a document in another window, ISTM that the node created by *importNode* is effectively identical to the one created through *createElement*.

Comment: @RobG: It seems relevant to me: `importNode()` exists and exists for a purpose. Fair points about cloning, obviously. The correct thing to do would be to have a look through the DOM spec to see whether using a node from another document should work, and I didn't really have time to do so.

Comment: @tim—I meant not relevant in the sense that the OP wishes to create an element in window A from a script in window A and append it to a document in Window B, whereas *importNode* will likely run in window B and create the new element in window B by cloning an element in window A. Though I guess the script could still be running in window A but the *document* in `document.importNode()` would be in window B.

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of variable access and potential DOM issues that probably won't hurt, it does not matter where you create an Element just where you append it.